# Pass props to makeStyles and use in CSS shorthand property in Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I pass props to a button component:

```
const StoreButton = ({ storeColor }) => {
  const borderBottom = `solid 3px ${storeColor}`;
  const classes = useStyles({ borderBottom });

  return (
    <Button variant="outlined" size="small" className={classes.button}>
      Store
    </ Button>
  )
};
```

I create the `borderBottom` property before I use it in classes. I would like to construct the property inside makeStyles but this leads to an error:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    borderBottom: props => props.borderBottom,
    // borderBottom: `solid 3px ${props => props.borderBottom}`; // function is pasted in
  },
}));
```

If I construct the CSS shorthand inside makeStyles it creates `solid 3px solid 3px function(props){return props.borderBottom;}`. when I inspect it in Chrome. Thus, this way the styles are invalid.

Is there a way to pass props to CSS shorthand properties without this workaround of creating it outside makeStyles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You almost had it right, the only thing to change is this:

```
borderBottom: props => `1px solid ${props.color}`,
```

Now the value is a proper function. Inside the function it constructs the correct string value.